# Creating a Simple "ORM/ActiveRecord" Pattern

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, orm

I am not sure what I'm doing is called ORM or Active Record Pattern.

I have an `Entity` base class that entities/database tables will inherit. These classes will have methods like

- find
- findBy
- findAllBy
- insert
- update
- delete
- Getters & Setters for column data (eg. name, title, etc) via magic methods

Problem now is how do I create a database connection?

- Dependency Injection - sounds complicated ...
- Use a global variable, that these classes will expect to be set? - Doesnt sound right
- Have a base class that `Entity` inherit that contain all database connection info? - doesnt sound right either

Maybe I am doing it wrong? I am open to any ideas, preferably simple for a start. I am wanting to create a simple framework for a start (not using Doctrine for example), it will give me a foundation on how such framework works. Also if its a small project, using a big framework may over-complicates things

Answer (score 0):

There isnt really much thats simple about what youre attempting. Its complex thing :-)

You need to have some kind of basic entity manager and/or table class which usually holds the reference to the DB connection (or some sort of object that wraps it). All the Entity's then pass themselves to the manager when their `save` or `delete` methods are called and the manager will work out the query needed to modify the db.

You can either inject this manager, or make it a singleton and have your classes fetch it when instantiated for example.

If i were you i would check out [PHP Objects Patterns and Practices by Matt Zandstra](http://www.apress.com/9781430229254). It goes into all these patterns with some basic implementation examples.